# eclipse external tools configurations -> referenced library in classpath does not exist: org.eclipse.swt

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath

After updating to the latest eclipse mars release

Version: Mars Release Candidate 1 (4.5.0RC1)
Build id: 20150521-1252

I am not able to start any Ant Script. It always results in the following error:

[image: ErrorDialog]

First I checked if the path is really correct, and made sure that the specific jar *org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150513-1901.jar* exists at the given location, which it does. After some digging I noticed the following within the external tools configurations:

[image: ExternalToolsConfiguration]

Somehow I think eclipse is not able to resolve the classpath with the given **'%20'** tag within the url to the library. Usually there is just a blank. Restoring the defaults always fills in the **'%20'** for this specific library.

So I created a copy of eclipse at a location without blanks and all works fine again.

Unfortunatly I would prefer keeping the location at it is, so is there a way to correctly resolve the classpath for **Additional Tasks & Support**?

Comment: I had a very similar experience on OSX and used the same workaround for Mars.

Comment: The problem still exists in Eclipse 4.5 ;-(

Comment: Eclipse 4.5.1 was released and the bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Eclipse Mars:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470390

**Update:** Eclipse 4.5.1 was released on October the 2nd and the bug has been fixed. An Eclipse update will resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks for poiting to the bug ticket. Seems its getting fixed soon then.

Comment: That does not answer the question and should be a comment.

Answer (score 4):

There is one other "fix" that's basically an easier workaround.

If you go to your Ant build configuration (under External Tools, then highlight your configuration and select the JRE tab) and change from running an external JRE to the top button, that is, "Run in the same JRE as the workspace", this will make it work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it's easy, explains why some build.xml might be executable, while others not and is tracable if you already version your launch files like I do. Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse 4.5.1 was released and the bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by moving C:\Program Files\eclipse to C:\eclipse

Answer also found here, [Eclipse Mars: ANT Task references missing SWT library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140101/eclipse-mars-ant-task-references-missing-swt-library)

Comment: That`s what I already mentioned in the question. Its just a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Eclipse 4.5.1 was released and the bug is now fixed.